# Select multiple files with the same extension in .bat file

Tags: file, batch-file, select, cmd, extension-methods

i found a script that converts a certain subtitle form , but to make it work i need to rename the subtitle file to `"test.srt"`, then after coonverting , i rename it back to its original name , and its really annoying to keep repeating the process and to name each subtitle file on its own , i want the script to convert all the files in that folder that ends up with `".srt"`, not only to `"test.srt"` file
the bat file is like this :

```
"perl ps3_friendly_arabic_subs_converter.pl test.srt"
```

it uses the perl script to convert the file named `"test.srt"` , i tried to make it convert  all the files that ends up with `".srt"` , and i edited it this way

```
"perl ps3_friendly_arabic_subs_converter.pl *.srt"
```

and yeah it didn't work , so please anyone knows how ? thanks in adnvance

Answer (score 1):

```
for %a in (*.srt) do perl ps3_friendly_arabic_subs_converter.pl "%a"
```

For each `.srt` file (in current folder), execute the indicated script passing the file as argument.

To execute it from a batch file, it is necessary to escape the percent signs, replacing each `%` with `%%`